# Creating styles in android without xml?

Tags: android, animation, styles

My question is.. Is it possible to create styles in android programmatically without any xml?

I wanted this because I need to use animation for a popup window when it enters and exits..
What i currently have is:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyAnimation" parent="android:Animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/in_animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/out_animation</item>
</style>
```

However, I want to decide the animation to use at runtime. This is because I would be calling the window which needs to be animated, on clicking some images on the screen.
These images are placed in horizontal scrollview and there are 4-5 such horizontal scrollviews on the screen.
And the animation I'm looking at is like..appearing from the view clicked, and growing to actual size alongwith translation to the center of the screen.
Since the position of images is not fixed, I cannot use an xml directly to specify the animation and hence need to make the style via code..

If there is any other way to achieve what i am aiming at, then please do let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Activity.overridePendingTransition()` method to get such behavior. This method accepts two animation resources: one for incoming activity and one for outgoing activity.

Comment: Hi Pixie..
this method can be used for activity -as you yourself said..
But i need to do it for PopupWindow.. and not for any activity..

But thanks for the info.. I wasn't aware about this method before. I learnt something new :)

Comment: Yes.. but it requires a style xml defined... which I have defined as mentioned in my question.
But I want to create this style without an xml as I would define the animations which are to be used at the runtime by the position of clicked view..
and once the xml is defined, there is no way to update the animations in that xml... or maybe I'm not aware about it.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be a problem.